# Efficient rows product using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code to get multiplication across rows of two different Numpy arrays. I have compared results with Numba too:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
from itertools import product    
from time import time


@jit( nopython=True)
def numba_product(a,b):

    a_len = len(a)
    b_len = len(b)
    n     = len( a[0,:] )

    c_res   = np.empty( (  a_len*b_len, n ), dtype=np.complex128 ) 
    c_count = 0  
    for i in range(a_len):
        for j in prange( b_len ):            
            c_res[ c_count , : ] = np.multiply( a[i,:], b[ j, : ]  )          
            c_count += 1
        
    return c_res

n= 100
iu = np.complex(0,1)
a = np.random.rand( n, 300 ) + iu*np.random.rand( n, 300 )
b = np.random.rand( n, 300 ) + iu*np.random.rand( n, 300 )


time_start = time()
c =  np.array( [ np.multiply( x[0],x[1] ) for x in  product( a,b ) ] )
time_end   = time()

print("--> time is %8.7f secs" % (time_end - time_start) )

c_r = numba_product( a,b )

time_start = time()
c_r = numba_product( a,b )
time_end   = time()
print("--> time is %8.7f secs" % (time_end - time_start) )
```

I know there must be an implementation of this in Numpy, that does this is in a more efficient way? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I just used the suggested answer and found the following times for execution ( shapes of "a" and "b" arrays are (100,300) ):

```
Itertools product + generator  --> 0.0712414 seconds 
Numba loops                    --> 0.0353553 seconds
index multiplication           --> 0.0302799 seconds
```

so there seems to be some improvement of around ~ 14%, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [54]: from itertools import product                                                  
In [55]: c =  np.array( [ np.multiply( x[0],x[1] ) for x in  product( a,b ) ] )         
In [56]: c.shape                                                                        
Out[56]: (10000, 300)
```

Looks like you are doing an outer product on the first dimensions - with flattening

```
In [57]: a.shape                                                                        
Out[57]: (100, 300)
In [58]: b.shape                                                                        
Out[58]: (100, 300)
In [59]: np.allclose((a[:,None,:]*b[None,:,:]).reshape(-1,300),c) 
Out[59]: True
```

I'll let you do the comparative timings

When you doing timings like this, a polite thing to do is to show the prints, the timing results.  That way we don't have to run things ourselves.  A little info on the results too, e.g. the shape.